# cakephp birthday helper customize the default values

Tags: forms, cakephp, form-helpers

I would like the to add "month", "day", "year" as the first choice in the birthday menu helper? Can this be done? I don't see any examples of how to do this? Below is the code I have:

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('date_of_birth', 
        array(
            'type' => 'date',
            'label' => 'Date of Birth:<span>*</span>',
            'dateFormat' => 'MDY',
            'empty' => true,
            'minYear' => date('Y')-130,
            'maxYear' => date('Y'),
            'options' => array('1','2')
            )
        );
    ?>
```

Thanks,
Bart

Comment: Not quite sure I do understand you. Are you trying to put the actual words `month`, `day` and `year` as the empty-options in the select lists?

Comment: Also which CakePHP version are you using?

Comment: Yes I am trying to put "month", "day", and "year" the words as the first field. I know I can hack the core, but would prefer not to. Also I see their is a month names array, which works for month. I just need to get day and year now. I am using cakephp 2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, [the `empty` option accepts an array](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.0/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L2413-L2420) where you can specify the empty value for the individual fields using the keys `month`, `year`, `day`, `hour`, `minute` and `meridian`:

```
echo $this->Form->input('date_of_birth', 
    array(
        'type' => 'date',
        'label' => 'Date of Birth:<span>*</span>',
        'dateFormat' => 'MDY',
        'empty' => array(
            'month' => 'Month',
            'day'   => 'Day',
            'year'  => 'Year'
        ),
        'minYear' => date('Y')-130,
        'maxYear' => date('Y'),
        'options' => array('1','2')
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a shot and let you know how it goes.